# Update value checking previous one - SQLObject

Tags: python, sqlobject

In an application already deployed, using [SQLObject](http://www.sqlobject.org/), I need to update a value *only* if the previous value match a certain value.

The equivalent sql could be:

```
UPDATE jobs SET status='150' WHERE id=1234 AND status='100'
```

I need this because we have many instances of a daemon on different servers (not knowing each others) which may want to take jobs and update the db to mark the job as "taken".

I want to prevent "double updates" from two nodes setting the same value.

It would be nice if I can get as a result the number of affected rows. With a result of 0 it would permit to say "job was already taken between fetch and update"...

The actual part of code doing the update looks like:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    """Override setattr to log build status changes"""
    [...]
    sqlobject.SQLObject.__setattr__(self, name, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLObject has a few API layers. There is no way to execute a conditional UPDATE if you use the high-level API (SQLObject-inhertied classes). `where`-clause is available in SQLBuilder's [Update](http://sqlobject.org/SQLBuilder.html#update).